# usual method of argument in the linkage theory

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Suppose that R is a CM local ring, and I and J are
two ideals of R. We say that I is algebraically linked to J
if there is an R-sequence **x** in $I \cap J$ such that I = **x** : J and
J = **x** : I.

In some articles about algebraic linkage theory, when I and J are two linked ideals, they say:
*We may apply the usual method of argument in the linkage theory to reduce
the proof to the case in which I = 0 : J and J = 0 : I with ht I = ht J = 0.*

**Question:** What is this ''*usual method of argument in the linkage theory*'' ?

Comment: Go modulo $\mathbf{x}$, $S=R/(\mathbf{x})$. Call the images of $I,J$, by $I',J'$. Then $S$ is CM and $I'=0:J'$ etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Mohan for your help